# Thermocouple IC MAX31856 circuit what is DRDY

Tags: thermocouple, max31856

I have a prototype board that seems to only output non-sensible values for K thermocouple readings, with no response to actual temperature changes.  Prior to this a breakout board with this exact IC [MAX31856MUD+T](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31856.pdf) and microcontroller connections was used.  The connections to the microcontroller are just SPI lines, V+, & GND.

However, looking at the datasheet there are two lines "DRDY" and "FAULT" which are not connected at all on this prototype.  Is this a problem or am I just losing out on extra features of the IC?

[image: circuit]

Also I found a schematic from Adafruit that I believe uses this IC.  They have pulled up their SPI lines.  Does this need to be done or are they just being precautious?  Thermocouple cable is about 3ft or so..

[image: Adafruit schematic]

Comment: You can certainly operate the chip without those connections. I suggest reading the datasheet carefully to see if the available modes of operation suit your individual application.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany should I consider pulling up the SPI lines as in the breakout board, or is this over engineering?

Comment: See the diodes? Looks like they're doing something funky to do 5V/3.3V conversion instead of  using a proper voltage translator chip.

Comment: Ah you are correct, they are tying into 5V microcontroller lines on an arduino

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet, I found the following. So you might probably need that line.

DRDY
The DRDY output goes low when a new conversion result
is available in the Linearized Thermocouple Temperature
register. When a read-operation of the Linearized
Thermocouple Temperature register or the Cold-Junction
Temperature Register (if enabled) completes, DRDY
returns high.

Answer (score 1):

The chip has features that are used via DRDY and FAULT pins. So when these pins are not available, yes, you are missing those features. It is not a problem if you don't need those features, but it is a problem if you need them, so it's up to you to decide if it is a problem or not depending on what you want to achieve with the chip and how you want to achieve it.

The SPI pins have diodes and pull-ups because it is a crude level shifter to interface a 3.3V chip to a 5V bus.